ignoring characters in lex/flex input or: understanding YY_INPUT
I'm parsing files with words that need to be spell checked. The input is in RTF-format.
The words to be checked have \- strings in them designating the predetermined breaking point where a word should be wrapped around when the line would get too long otherwise (hyphenation).
The input is e.g.   ei\-ner. The lexer should recognize 'einer', thus totally ignoring the '\-'.
The task could be boiled down to:
parse the input for the occurrence of '\-'.
eliminate the '\-' from the input stream (yyin/yytext) and put back the
filtered input stream to the lexer.
Or in other words: is it possible to make flex, to ignore a pattern totally?

There are ways. You could just post-process the words. Or you could concatenate part of words in some variable and return it only if you encounter a non-word character. In your case I would also consider writing your own lexer since this would allow you more freedom and the tokens of RTF seem to be rather simple to detect.

You mean, pre-process? I have to detect "einer", but '-' gets in the way and prevents lexical detection. An idea came to me. See followup post.

By post-processing I meant that you won't just strdup yytext into yyval (I'm assuming C language) but instead you copy only the characters that are not \-. (It's hard to tell you exactly what to change without seeing a minimal example that I could comment on.)

I believe I got the idea. I might override YY_INPUT.
In lex.yy.cit is defined as:
   #ifndef YY_INPUT
#define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size) \
    if ( YY_CURRENT_BUFFER_LVALUE->yy_is_interactive ) \
        { \
        int c = '*'; \
        int n; \
        for ( n = 0; n < max_size && \
                 (c = getc( yyin )) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++n ) \
            buf[n] = (char) c; \
        if ( c == '\n' ) \
            buf[n++] = (char) c; \
        if ( c == EOF && ferror( yyin ) ) \
            YY_FATAL_ERROR( "input in flex scanner failed" ); \
        result = n; \
        } \
    else \
        { \
        errno=0; \
        while ( (result = (int) fread(buf, 1, (yy_size_t) max_size, yyin)) == 0 && ferror(yyin)) \
            { \
            if( errno != EINTR) \
                { \
                YY_FATAL_ERROR( "input in flex scanner failed" ); \
                break; \
                } \
            errno=0; \
            clearerr(yyin); \
            } \
        }\
\

#endif

and put my input filtering in there. The only problem I see is, when I "eat up" two characters from the input and flex is asking max_size characters, how do I tell the caller that there are two less in the buffer?
EDIT: maybe I just correct result so the caller gets notice of that, whatever consequence it takes from that.
EDIT: example
Let l1.l be:
%{
#include <stdio.h>

int yylex(void);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        if((yyin= fopen(argv[1],"r")) == NULL) {
            printf("can't open %s",argv[1]),exit(-1);
        }
         while(yylex())
          ;
    return 0;
}
%}
%option noyywrap
%%
"einer" { fprintf(yyout,"einer found"); }
%

And the input file einer.txt:
ei\-ner 

What I would like to recognize is:
einer found

I wouldn't mess with YY_INPUT without a good reason. It isn't meant to be tinkered with unless you need to do something related to loading raw data. If you modify the input there, you can have problems later with tracking position in file (e.g. to show the user where the error is).

But that's what the macro #define YY_INPUT is made for. To substitute YY_INPUT().

It's to change input to your lexer. For example, you may want to load data directly from an internet connection. Or you may convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 before applying rules to it. It is possible to use it to remove sequences \- but it won't be easier to do this in YY_INPUT than in some post-processing step and it will cause much more potential problems.

my application needs to have the pattern "\-" (a backslash followed by a minus sign) filtered from the input stream before applying the lexer (as described in my initial post").  The backslash- sequence disturbs the lexing process.

I don't really see this. Could you edit your question and post some code that demonstrates the problem?

Edited my post showing the status quo

I meant question but ok.
Is "einer" really the only string you accept? I would assume you have some regex to find words, like [A-Za-z]+. I can give you an advice that works only for "einer", though, if you want.

„einer“ ist just an example to show the problem or the intention. You could extend it to any „word“ as [A-Za-z]+ would cover. Interested in your  suggestion anyway.

I'm really not comfortable with making suggestions without seeing the relevant part of your actual code. I'll probable end up with something you can't use.

Actually my question aims at "ignoring characters in lex/flex input" and I would like to stay with following to find an answer to this question and not setting out for an alternate solution. Thus understanding the YY_INPUT macro is the primary goal.

I don't know YY_INPUT that much except that this is not something you should touch without a good reason. If you insist on going that way, this is all the documentation I can find: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/flex-2.5.4/html_node/flex_10.html

If you want exclusively answers about YY_INPUT, you should change your question. If you leave it like that, an answer will likely focus on some other method and it would be a jerk move if you then tell that's not what you're looking for.

It's difficult to change my original question to something like "understanding YY_INPUT in lex/flex" .  So what do now? Actually it is no rocket science, though this while  on fread returning 0 is a bit funny. I'll give it a try and  change the question.
